Listing Folders and Files with the same name
I have a folder with extracted ZIP files in it.
(Extracted ZIP folders are the same name as the ZIP file without ZIP in the folder name
Example: File1.zip extracts to the file1 folder
I need to show only the folders that have a matching filename. By that I meant I would like to do one of the following:
Move both matching files and folders into a sub folder OR
Hide the matching files and folders so I know what zip files haven't extracted.
Also how can I find the zip file it left off with when I shutdown the PC? I will need to re extract that file.
My desktop crashed, so I restarted and lost the progress of extracting hundreds of ZIP files. That's why I need a script to know what files extracted.

I think there's a safer way to approach this that will also fix a (most likely present) partially extracted archive. Can you share the exact command you ran in order to extract all the .zip files?

If you switch to zsh in place of bash, you could use a glob qualifier to execute shell code that tests whether a directory exists matching the root (basename) of each zip file, [[ -d $REPLY:r ]]. Ex. given
 % ls -pd --group-directories-first File*
File1/  File3/  File1.zip  File2.zip  File3.zip

then to list zip files that do have corresponding unzipped directories
 % print -r *.zip(Ne%'[[ -d $REPLY:r ]]'%) 
File1.zip File3.zip

or the complement
 % print -r *.zip(Ne%'[[ ! -d $REPLY:r ]]'%)
File2.zip


You could do the same test in bash using an explicit loop e.g.
for f in *.zip; do [[ -d ${f%.zip} ]] || echo "$f has not been unzipped"; done


I Really appreciate your work! Since I am not using zsh, I went with your last option in bash, and it worked flawlessly!
